# CALayer animation issue

Tags: ios, animation, calayer

I am trying to animate different CALayers, but only the last animation works.

I am baiscally doing this to create different CALayers that contain text and add animation to each one. Here is the code that generates the CALayers:

```
    // Create a layer for the title
    CALayer *_watermarkLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [_watermarkLayer setOpacity:0];

    // Create a layer for the text of the title.
    CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    titleLayer.string = text;
    titleLayer.foregroundColor = [color CGColor];
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width/2, videoSize.height/2); 
    [_watermarkLayer addSublayer:titleLayer];

    // Fade in/out animation
    NSString* aux = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", seconds];
    CABasicAnimation *fadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeAnimation.additive = YES;
    fadeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    fadeAnimation.beginTime = seconds;
    fadeAnimation.duration = 2.0;
    fadeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved; 
    [_watermarkLayer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:[@"animateOpacity" stringByAppendingString:aux]];
```

I am using the CALayer obtained from the above code like this:

```
- (void) addWatermarkWithVideoComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition*)videoComposition withLabel:(NSString*)text andColor:(UIColor*)color andBeginTimeInSeconds:(int)seconds
{
    // Setup video layers
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoComposition.renderSize.width, videoComposition.renderSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoComposition.renderSize.width, videoComposition.renderSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];

    // Create and add watermark layer
    CALayer *exportWatermarkLayer = [self watermarkLayerForSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300) andText:text andColor:color andBeginTimeInSeconds:seconds];
    exportWatermarkLayer.position = CGPointMake(videoComposition.renderSize.width/2, videoComposition.renderSize.height/4);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:exportWatermarkLayer];

    // Merge layers
    videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
}
```

Usage:

```
AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComposition.instructions = instructions;
    videoComposition.renderSize = outputSize;
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    [self addWatermarkWithVideoComposition:videoComposition withLabel:@"Tag" andColor:lastColor andBeginTimeInSeconds:0];
    [self addWatermarkWithVideoComposition:videoComposition withLabel:@"Tag" andColor:lastColor andBeginTimeInSeconds:3];
    [self addWatermarkWithVideoComposition:videoComposition withLabel:@"Tag" andColor:lastColor andBeginTimeInSeconds:5];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:preset];
....................
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I see there is only a single layer and animation in that code

Comment: Sorry, updated the code now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are three issues in your code. You might want to:

1. Change `fadeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;` to `... = NO;`.
2. Change `fadeAnimation.fillMode = xyz;` to `... =
       kCAFillModeForwards;`
3. Change the `.beginTime` of all CALayers and all CAAnimations that
       you want to export with the AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool that
       currently have `beginTime == 0.0` (which is the default value!!) to
       `AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero`.

More details about this can be found in Apple's documentation of [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It's not nice that the `beginTime` hint is not also mentioned in Apples documentation of the beginTime property in the [CAMediaTiming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming) protocol.

I had a similar issue, with only those animations working, where I explicitly set a (non-zero) beginTime. Hopefully this is the solution for your problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to create a watermark `CALayer` to the center of video, it's working on osx `Cocoa`. Hope it would be helpful.

```
- (CALayer *)createLayerImage:(NSString *)imagePath videoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
{
    CALayer *watermarkLayer = [CALayer layer];
    NSImage *watermarkImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    [watermarkLayer setContents:watermarkImage];
    [watermarkLayer setFrame:CGRectMake((videoSize.width-watermarkImage.size.width)/2,
                                        (videoSize.height-watermarkImage.size.height)/2,
                                        watermarkImage.size.width,
                                        watermarkImage.size.height)];
    NSLog(@"watermark layer %fx%f", watermarkImage.size.width, watermarkImage.size.height);
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.duration = 5.0;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [watermarkLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];

    return watermarkLayer;
}
```